# How to getArray from JdbcResultSet in google app script?

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script

I am able to loop though and get results to an array from jdbc result, but I am wondering how to do this with getArray().

```
var results = stmt.executeQuery("select col1, col2 from sometable;");
var arr1 = results.getArray("col1");
```

Also, how to just dump or inspect the results object in google app script ?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code. It's based in this example from the official docs:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#read_from_the_database

```js
  //Execute query
    var results = stmt.executeQuery("select col1, col2 from sometable;"); 
  
  //Generate a 2d array to insert in spreadsheet
  var array2d = [];
  
  //Generate array with titles                               
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  var titles = [];
  
  for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++){
    var colName = results.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(col + 1);
    titles.push(colName);
  }
  
  //Insert titles in 2d array
  array2d.push(titles);
  
  //Extract results from query and insert insert into array2d
  
  while (results.next()) {
    //This is an array with data from each row
    rowData = [];
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {      
          rowData.push(results.getString(col + 1));
    }
    //Insert data from each row in 2d array
    array2d.push(rowData);
  }
  
  //close  
  results.close();
  
  Logger.log(array2d);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  .getRange(1, 1, Object.keys(array2d).length, array2d[0].length)
  .setValues(array2d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to first check [Class JdbcArray](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-array) and the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html) of this class.

As discussed in [java.sql.Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html),

> The Array interface provides methods for bringing an SQL ARRAY value's data to the client as either an array or a `ResultSet` object. If the elements of the SQL ARRAY are user defined data type (UDT), they may be custom mapped.

To create a custom mapping, you must do two things:

> - create a class that implements the SQLData interface for the UDT to be custom mapped.
> - make an entry in a type map that contains
>
>   - the fully-qualified SQL type name of the UDT
>   - the Class object for the class implementing SQLData

After which, you can then check [Class JdbcResultSet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-result-set) and its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

Lastly, [Guide to JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) might also help.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you speaking about implementation in google's app script ?  And would you have an example of this implementation ?  Thanks!